# Potential issue with move for Compound Graph [cytoscape.js]?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I've been experimenting Compound Graph editor based on Cytoscape.js.

I created a function for adding a compound node for a set of selected nodes with the same parent.

Roughly, it is first tested if the selected nodes have the same parent. If the case, a new node is create, as a child of the parent, and all the selected nodes are moved to this new node.

It seems to work well.

E.g. I created a set of nodes, and grouped them with two levels of decomposition the following way.

[A hierarchy of compound nodes created with the created functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gigHO.png)

However, when trying to apply the function on a set of nodes at layer 2 as illustrated in the next figure:
[Initiating grouping for a set of nodes layer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNSxQ.png)

The result is quite surprising, as illustrated in the next figure. The hierarchy of compound nodes is fully changed, while applying exactly the same algorithm than previously.
[result of using the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YrpC.png)

So I'm wondering if somebody already faced this, and if any idea concerning the reason of this behavior.

In order to debug, I tried to identify the place where the move function is defined in the code (but I didn't succeed yet) in order to put a breakpoint on the call to the move function and to identify which part of the code could cause the unexpected change of parents.

So if someone know where I can find this piece of code, it will also be helpful for understanding where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Didn't you call the `move` function by yourself? It is totally related to that. Maybe ID of the compounds is somehow wrong. How can we help you to find "the piece of code" when you didn't share any piece of code?

Comment: Hi Canbax, thanks for your response. Yes I used the move function. A this stage, I didn't yet shared the code as it is a huge piece of software. The reason why I first described the effect, in case someone already faced similar issue.
What I will do is trying to reproduce it with a simplified code, and share it.

Comment: I finally succeeded in finding the reason of this behavior: the way to find the selector for move is not the good one: I used cy.$(nodeId) and not cy.$id(nodeId). If some selector error is signaled in the log. However, the program is not stopped. The the initial hierarchy loss is a border effect of the selector error for the move instruction.

Comment: `cy.$('#' + nodeId)` and `cy.$id(nodeId)` are identical. It is just the syntax

Comment: I didn't use the '#' => Message was "invalid selector" and the effect border was the whole hierarchy being changed.